# how to find maximum spanning tree using prims algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

I want to modify Prim's algorithm so that it find the maximum spanning tree how can this be done

Answer (score 1):

Prim's algorithm doesn't mind negative weights.

Simply flip the sign of every edge's weight, and use the minimum spanning tree algorithm.

Comment: are you sure that it does not assume that you cannot decrease the "weight" of the tree by adding new branches?

Answer (score 0):

Even going greedy for maximum edge instead of minimum edge will help.